# Android Studio error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/miginfocom/layout/PlatformDefaults

Tags: android-studio, android-x86

I recently unzipped the latest Windows 10 32-bit Android Studio version and followed the guide to running the program. Everything was unzipped properly. When I run the android studio application, it gave me an error.

Here is what it looks like:

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/miginfocom/layout/PlatformDefaults at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.patchSystem(IdeaApplication.java:174) at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.(IdeaApplication.java:84) at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$start$1(MainImpl.java:45) at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762) at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.miginfocom.layout.PlatformDefaults at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:224) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 17 more

Please help. I do not know what java.lang.ClassNotFoundException means.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java